# How to load the state of checkboxlist in database asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

got 2 checkboxlists , each checkbox has 6 checkboxes inside it (below is my database)

checkboxlist1 : id , rowa

checkboxlist2:id , rowb

```
 id       : int
 rowa : nvarchar(250)
 rowb : nvarchar(250)
```

When I click one checkbox, the value is saved to my database as A1 , A2.... Here is my code:

```
 Dim str1 As [String] = ""
    For a As Integer = 0 To CheckBoxList1.Items.Count - 1

        If CheckBoxList1.Items(a).Selected Then

            If str1 = "" Then
                str1 = CheckBoxList1.Items(a).Text
            Else

                str1 += "," + CheckBoxList1.Items(a).Text
                str1 = ""

            End If
        End If

    Next
    For a1 As Integer = 0 To CheckBoxList1.Items.Count - 10
        CheckBoxList1.Enabled = False
    Next

    Dim str2 As [String] = ""
    For b As Integer = 0 To CheckBoxList2.Items.Count - 1

        If CheckBoxList2.Items(b).Selected Then

            If str2 = "" Then
                str2 = CheckBoxList2.Items(b).Text
            Else

                str2 += "," + CheckBoxList2.Items(b).Text


            End If
        End If
    Next
```

> Dim connectionString As String =
>   ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
>   Dim insertSql As String = "INSERT INTO tbtest(rowa,rowb)VALUES(@rowa,@rowb)"
>   Using myConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
>       myConnection.Open()
>       Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(insertSql, myConnection)
>       myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowa", str1) 
>       myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowb", str2)
>        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() 
>        myConnection.Close() 
>        End Using

- But somehow, when I load the page, it does not show the checked state
  (checked/unchecked). Here is my code in page load.  So my question is
  ?

  1. How to show the checked state of checkboxlist ?
  2. I try to save the state in session , but when i check a blank checkbox , it will then 
     save all the checked value to my database , how to avoid this ? i mean i want to save 
     only the value which is unchecked to database ?
  3. If it is possible can you make the checked checkboxes disable ?

> Page_load
>
> ```
>  Dim connectionString As String =
> ```
>
> Using myConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
>       Dim objCmd_team As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT [rowa],[rowb] FROM [tbtest]", myConnection)
>       myConnection.Open()
>       Dim objReader As SqlDataReader = objCmd_team.ExecuteReader()
>
> ```
> While (objReader.Read())
>     Dim currentCheckBox As ListItem = checkboxlist1.Items.FindByText(objReader("rowa"))
>
>     If currentCheckBox IsNot Nothing Then
>         currentCheckBox.Selected = True
>     End If Dim currentCheckBox1 As ListItem = checkboxlist2.Items.FindByText(objReader("rowb"))
>     If currentCheckBox1 IsNot Nothing Then
>         currentCheckBox1.Selected = True
>     End If  End While  End Using
> ```